# using javax.cache.CacheManager with EhCache

Tags: ehcache, distributed-caching

I am trying to use javax.cache.CacheManager JSR107 API using EhCache as caching solutioarin provider. But I am unable to find any such resources.

As per the link at http://ehcache.org/documentation/integrations/jsr107 , it says that ehcache jsr107 is still in draft phase. Can any one please confirm if it's still the case?

Any sample code to use net sf cacheManager using JSR107 javax.cache.* classes?

Thanks,
Harish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As specified in [this page](http://Because%20JCACHE%20has%20not%20yet%20been%20released%20the%20JCACHE%20API%20that%20Ehcache%20implements%20has%20been%20released%20as%20net.sf.jsr107cache.):

> Because JCACHE has not yet been released the JCACHE API that Ehcache
>   implements has been released as net.sf.jsr107cache.

This effort can be found [in the Github repository](https://github.com/jsr107/ehcache-jcache). If you see [JCacheManager](https://github.com/jsr107/ehcache-jcache/blob/master/ehcache-jcache/src/main/java/net/sf/ehcache/jcache/JCacheManager.java) implements javax.cache.CacheManager

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better answer now the API is finalised.  Stick this in your pom:

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcache</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsr107.ri</groupId>
        <artifactId>cache-annotations-ri-guice</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

And you're off.  Annotate with any of the annotations like this: (good luck finding the javadocs!)

```
@CacheResult(cacheName = "monthly")
public List<QueryResult> monthly(String prefix) {
    //...
}
```

I agree though, the documentation sucks.

Here's [more javax.cache info](http://demeranville.com/how-to-set-up-method-level-caching-with-annotations-using-javax-cache-jcache-jsr-107-and-guice/) if you're interested.